# SQL - "incrementing" a char value causes collation error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

I'm dealing with a table in which a bunch of arbitrary settings are stored as `VARCHAR(255)` values. The particular one I'm tasked with dealing with is a sequence number that needs to be incremented and returned to the caller. (Again, note that the sequence "number" is stored as `VARCHAR`, which is something I don't have any control over).

Because it's a sequence number, I don't really want to select and update in separate steps. When I've dealt with this sort of thing in the past with actual numeric fields, my method has been something like

```
UPDATE TABLE SET @SEQ_NUM = VALUE = VALUE + 1
```

which increments the value and gives me the updated value in one swell foop. I thought in this situation, I'd try the same basic thing with casts:

```
DECLARE @SEQ_NUM VARCHAR(255)

UPDATE SOME_TABLE
    SET @SEQ_NUM = VALUE = CAST((CAST(VALUE AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) 
WHERE NAME = 'SOME_NAME'
```

The actual update works fine so long as I don't try to assign the result to the variable; as soon as I do, I receive the following error:

> Msg 549, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The collation
>   'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' of receiving variable is not equal to
>   the collation 'Latin1_General_BIN' of column 'VALUE'.

I understand what that means, but I don't understand why it's happening, or by extension, how to remedy the issue.

As an aside to fixing the specific error, I'd welcome suggestions for alternative approaches to incrementing a char sequence "number".

Comment: Why are you even trying to maintain your own sequence number? It is fraught with issues like concurrency. Because the person who designed this wasn't thinking you are going to be fighting a loosing battle here.

Comment: You can probably fix the problem by using the `COLLATE` keyword.

Comment: @SeanLange, believe me, I know. Fortunately, this particular use case won't be exercised often, but it's still a massive PITA.

Comment: @GordonLinoff--how, exactly? I'd tried forcing the COLLATE on the calculated value like so: 'SET SEQ_NUM = VALUE = CAST((CAST(VALUE AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', but received the same error. I'm unaware of a way to set the COLLATE value on the variable itself (not that my being unaware of something means anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of the comments, sounds like you may have already hit on this, but here's what I would recommend:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET VALUE = CAST((CAST(VALUE AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) 
OUTPUT inserted.VALUE
WHERE NAME = 'SOME_NAME'
```

This will output the new value like a `SELECT` statement does. You can also cast `inserted.VALUE` to an `int` if you wanted to do that in the SQL.

If you wanted to put the value into `@SEQ_NUM` instead of outputing the value from the statement/stored procedure, you can't use a scalar variable, but you can pump it into a table variable, like so:

```
DECLARE @SEQ_NUM AS TABLE ( VALUE VARCHAR(255) );

UPDATE TABLE
SET VALUE = CAST((CAST(VALUE AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) 
OUTPUT inserted.VALUE INTO @SEQ_NUM ( VALUE )
WHERE NAME = 'SOME_NAME'

SELECT VALUE FROM @SEQ_NUM
```

Comment: that's pretty much exactly what I'm doing right now. I'm doing this update in a stored proc and need to return the value; is there a streamlined alternative to inserting the output into a table var and selecting the value back out? I'm not really familiar with the operation of OUTPUT if it's not inserting into a table var.

Comment: So, both these code blocks will do the exact same thing - output the new value from the stored procedure. If you don't need to manipulate the value in the sproc, then use the first block, and when you read the data returned in the code (e.g., via `ExecuteScalar`), it'll have the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining a sequential number manually is by no means a solution I'd like to work with, but I can understand there might be constraints around this.

If you break it down in to 2 steps, then you can work around the issue. Note I've replaced your `WHERE` clause for this example code to work:

```
CREATE TABLE #SOME_TABLE ( [VALUE] VARCHAR(255) )

INSERT  INTO #SOME_TABLE
        ( VALUE )
VALUES  ( '12345' )

DECLARE @SEQ_NUM VARCHAR(255) 

UPDATE  #SOME_TABLE
SET     [VALUE] = CAST(( CAST([VALUE] AS INT) + 1 ) AS VARCHAR(255))
WHERE   1 = 1

SELECT  *
FROM    #SOME_TABLE

SELECT  @SEQ_NUM = [VALUE]
FROM    #SOME_TABLE
WHERE   1 = 1

SELECT  @SEQ_NUM

DROP TABLE #SOME_TABLE
```

Comment: I haven't gotten around to trying this alternate method yet, but I was thinking about a similar approach to what you've outlined except by using a table var and the OUTPUT clause in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using the quirky update in OP but you have to split the triple assignment `@Variable = Column = Expression` in the `UPDATE` statement to two simple assignments of `@Variable = Expression` and `Column = @Variable` like this

```
CREATE TABLE #SOME_TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(255)
    , VALUE VARCHAR(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
    )
INSERT #SOME_TABLE SELECT 'SOME_NAME', '42'

DECLARE @SEQ_NUM VARCHAR(255)

/*
-- this quirky update fails on COLLATION mismatch or data-type mismatch
UPDATE #SOME_TABLE
    SET @SEQ_NUM = VALUE = CAST((CAST(VALUE AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) 
WHERE NAME = 'SOME_NAME'
*/

-- this quirky update works in all cases
UPDATE #SOME_TABLE
    SET @SEQ_NUM = CAST((CAST(VALUE AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) 
        , VALUE = @SEQ_NUM
WHERE NAME = 'SOME_NAME'

SELECT *, @SEQ_NUM FROM #SOME_TABLE
```

This simple rewrite prevents db-engine complaining on difference in data-type between `@Variable` and `Column` too (e.g. `VARCHAR` vs `NVARCHAR`) and seems like a more "portable" way of doing quirky updates (if there is such thing)